# XSL-FOで見出しを作成したい

Tags: xsl, xsl-fo

XSL-FOで見出し作成したいと考えています。
縦組みの本文です。
見出しは本文フォントサイズの2倍、blockの開始より4文字文の字下げ、位置は3文字分の中央に設置したいと考えています。
XSL-FOではどのように表現すれば良いでしょうか？

■■■
■見■
■出■
■し■
■■■

見出し文字の幅は本文の文字の幅より大きくなるかと思います。

Comment: 「位置は3文字分の中央」というのは具体的にはどのようなレイアウトでしょうか？？

Comment: 質問の内容を編集しました。--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようなFOで実現できます．

- 「見出しは本文フォントサイズの2倍」：見出しの内側の`fo:block`の`font-size="2em"`
- 「blockの開始より4文字文の字下げ」：見出しの外側の`fo:block`の`text-indent="4em"`
- 「位置は3文字分の中央に設置」：見出し3文字分と解釈して、内側の`fo:block`の`line-height="3em"`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Meiryo" font-size="16pt" line-height="1.2">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" master-name="spm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-right="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" border="thin solid green" writing-mode="tb-rl"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm" writing-mode="from-page-master-region()">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <!--見出し-->
            <fo:block text-indent="4em">
                <fo:block font-size="2em" line-height="3em">グスコーブドリの伝記</fo:block>
            </fo:block>
            <!--本文-->
            <fo:block text-indent="1em">グスコーブドリは、イーハトーヴの大きな森のなかに生まれました。おとうさんは、グスコーナドリという名高い木こりで、どんな大きな木でも、まるで赤ん坊を寝かしつけるようにわけなく切ってしまう人でした。</fo:block>
            <fo:block text-indent="1em">ブドリにはネリという妹があって、二人は毎日森で遊びました。ごしっごしっとおとうさんの木を挽く音が、やっと聞こえるくらいな遠くへも行きました。二人はそこで木いちごの実をとってわき水につけたり、空を向いてかわるがわる山鳩の鳴くまねをしたりしました。するとあちらでもこちらでも、ぽう、ぽう、と鳥が眠そうに鳴き出すのでした。</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

組版結果（AH Formatter）

[image: サンプル組版結果]